# Cannot start, view, or deploy ARM VMs - BadGateway

Tags: azure

We recently deployed AVD. Everything was working great.  I created all the networking, set up a site-to-site VPN to our on-prem network with a [forced tunnel](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-forced-tunneling-rm#configure-forced-tunneling-1).  I deployed a VM to make my gold image.  tested connectivity.  everything worked great.  I deployed the session hosts, they joined to the domain, etc, etc.  I came in today and now the session hosts won't even start.  I either get (Code: ServerTimeout) or (Code: BadGatway).  If I try to view them in the azure portal it just loads endlessly.  I also am not able to deploy new VMs to that subnet.  It **seems** like a routing issue but I can't imagine why it would suddenly stop working.  I'm seriously at a loss.

I have a NSG on the subent with the default rules and I have a UDR with a single default rout that points to the virutal gateway.  I'm not even sure what else to check.  I even tried changing the DNS servers back to the azure provided ones from our internal DNS thinking maybe DNS resolution may have been a problem.

Any ideas on what I can troubleshoot next is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: seems like the next step would be to raise a ticket with Microsoft Support from the problematic resource blade. Do you have a support plan with them?

Answer (score 0):

It magically and mysteriously started working this morning.  I'm not aware of any Azure outages or anything that might have impacted this, but I'm going to chalk it up to Gremlins.  Thank you all for your responses